# Primefaces commandButton and ajax

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I use a `tabView` component with many tabs. In many of them, I have `form` which are submitted by primefaces `commandButton` component.

By default, PF `commandButton` using ajax mode but when I submit my form, my page seems to be fully loaded and my `tabView` component lost its index view (index 0 is rendered).

Is that normal behaviour please ?

I though that I would stay in the same index because it's ajax...

Comment: your tab index should stay the same... take a look at your browser console for some js errors... which may result in full page reload... also , any chance you use `h:commandButton` or `p:commandButton ajax="false"`  ?

Comment: With firebug, I have no JS error displayed. My commandButton code is this one : `<p:commandButton ajax="true" value="#{sf:firstLetterUppercase(rb.REGISTER)}" onclick="return validateRegisterForm();" action="#{login.registerAccount}" />
`

Comment: Ok, when I create new tab and fill it with very basic form and PF commandButton, I keep the right index so perhaps it's a nested component in my form which force the change of index at reload. I will check my code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some naming container (`p:tabView` maybe) that you better assign an `id` to it , so instead of getting prefix like `j_idt16` (which could vary from time to time) you will get `myTab0` , `myTab1` etc prefix...

for example `<p:tabView id="myTab"`

Another thing you could do to be on the safe side is checking if the element exists before trying to select it with jquery and access its value, like this

```
if($('#j_idt16\\:register_location_choice_2_input').length > 0){
    //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem is the JS `validateRegisterForm` function. When I remove it, it works but I need it...

I use it to check if validation form can be launched.

```
function validateRegisterForm(){    

if($('#j_idt16\\:register_location_choice_2_input').attr('checked')){

    if($('#j_idt16\\:register_galaxies_input').val() == 0){
        var galaxie = MUST_CHOOSE_GALAXY;
        alert(galaxie.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + galaxie.slice(1));
        return false;
    }

    if($('#j_idt16\\:register_solar_systems_input').val() == 0){
        var ss = MUST_CHOOSE_SOLAR_SYSTEM;
        alert(ss.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ss.slice(1));
        return false;
    }

    if($('#j_idt16\\:register_positions_input').val() == 0){
        var position = MUST_CHOOSE_POSITION;
        alert(position.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + position.slice(1));
        return false;
    }

}


return true;
```

}

So how can I check fields values before sending and allowing or not validation form with ajax please ?

**EDIT :**

Ok, I solved my problem by launching validation inside my JS function with button `type` passed to `button` not `submit` and using `remoteCommand` component :

My JS function :

```
function validateRegisterForm(){    

if(...)
      validateForm();
```

}

And my `remoteCommand` :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="validateForm" actionListener="#{login.registerAccount()}"/>
```

Comment: question ;) look at the '?'